# How do I add additional queryParams to current URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using React's use history hook to create query params in URL. After filling out a name and clicking a button, my URL changes from "xyz.com/#/customer" to "xyz.com/#customer?name=rabin". Then, after some background processing from an API, we get their phone number. I would like to add the phone number to currentUrl like

"xyz.com/#customer?name=rabin&phone=682222333".

I tried the following approach.

1. history.push(`phone=${phone}`) -> Result = "xyz.com/#customer?&phone=682222333"
2. history.push(pathname: `window.location.hash.substring(2)`, search=`phone=${phone}`) -> Result = "xyz.com/#customer?name=rabin&?phone=682222333"

I am not able to create this "xyz.com/#customer?name=rabin&phone=682222333". Please help. I have been stuck on this for 3 days.

Comment: which react-router version are you using?

Comment: react-router-dom : "^5.2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object from the current `location.search` value. You can then mutate the `searchParams` object and issue an imperative navigation with the updated queryString.

Example:

```
const { search } = useLocation();
const history = useHistory();

const searchParams = useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);

...

searchParams.set("phone", "682222333");
history.push({
  pathname: "/customer",
  search: searchParams.toString();
});
// or history.push(`/customer?${searchParams.toString()}`);
```